# Comma-separate list of JSON object keys

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql

I have a **varchar** column in my Postgres table that has a value like this:

```
{
    "vars": {
        "props": [{
                "a": "testA1",
                "b": "testB1",
                "c": "testC1"
            },
            {
                "a": null,
                "b": "testB2",
                "c": "testB3"
            }, {
                "a": "testA3",
                "b": "testB3",
                "c": "testC3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to get the list of all the "a" keys that are not null, and comma-separate them. It should look like this:

**testA1,testA3**

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option that works by casting the string to a jsonb datatype, then expending the `'props'` aray to rows with `jsonb_array_elements()`, filtering on non-null `a` values and aggregating:

```
select t.id, string_agg(j.v ->> 'a', ',') vals
from mytable t
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements( (js::jsonb) -> 'vars' -> 'props') j(v)
where j.v ->> 'a'  is not null
group by t.id
```

This supposes that you have a primary key or unique column that can be used to keep track of each unnested record.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=61bf80f2c8c0cb8999928bd6247746cf)**:

```
with mytable as (
    select 1 id, '{
    "vars": {
        "props": [
            {
                "a": "testA1",
                "b": "testB1",
                "c": "testC1"
            },
            {
                "a": null,
                "b": "testB2",
                "c": "testB3"
            }, {
                "a": "testA3",
                "b": "testB3",
                "c": "testC3"
            }
        ]
    }
}' js
)
select t.id, string_agg(j.v ->> 'a', ',') vals
from mytable t
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements( (js::jsonb) -> 'vars' -> 'props') j(v)
where j.v ->> 'a'  is not null
group by t.id
```

```
id | vals
-: | :------------
 1 | testA1,testA3
```